# alpine.js select/option init value

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have the following select/option input

```html
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ selected_id: 1, options: [{label: 'Foo', id: 0}, {label: 'Bar', id: 1}] }">
  <select x-model="selected_id">
    <template x-for="option in options">
      <option :value="option.id" x-text="option.label"></option>
    </template>
  </select>
  <div x-text="selected_id"></div>
</div>
```

The initial selected value is `Foo` but the I specified `select_id` as `1` which corresponds to `Bar`.

How can I set the initial selected value based on the value of `selected_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/495

```html
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ selected_id: 1, options: [{label: 'Foo', id: 0}, {label: 'Bar', id: 1}] }">
  <select x-model="selected_id">
    <template x-for="option in options">
      <option :value="option.id" x-text="option.label" :selected="option.id == selected_id"></option>
    </template>
  </select>
  <div x-text="selected_id"></div>
</div>
```